# amp-html http protocol restriction

Tags: forms, validation, amp-html

I have added AMP to my project and trying to figure out an validation issue with `http` protocol in form action. In the official example, I can see that it is possible to have relative URL: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/forms.amp.html

1) when I try to use relative URL it becomes invalid

**The relative URL '/amp/someurl' for attribute 'action' in tag 'form' is disallowed.**

2) when I try to use absolute URL, it complains about protocol

**Invalid URL protocol 'http:' for attribute 'action' in tag 'form'.**

the last error disappears when I use `https` instead of `http`. But the problem is that the website does not have `https` and the form is being used just for searching.

Maybe I have to use some `<amp-iframe>` in order to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the [`<amp-form>` specifications](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-form.html), you can't use a relative path for the `action` attribute and it must be `https`. The same goes for `<amp-iframe>`, you need `https` for the `src` attribute.

The reason for the mandatory `https` protocol is because AMP pages are cached on Google AMP servers and when served from AMP servers, they will be delivered over `https`. Now if you had `http` requests in your page, then they will be blocked for security reasons.